# convert groups of x columns from columns to rows numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 5x8 array (for example)

```
[[ 43 153  39  40 157 116  78 165]
 [108 182  42 244  28  67  59 176]
 [ 44  81 236 229 102  32 176 237]
 [143 218  78  77 237 194 135 251]
 [247  37 143  89 100 188 156 206]]
```

I'd like to write it out as a 10x4 array.  Not a simple reshape but I'd like to take the first two columns 0 and 1 and leave them as they are.  Columns 2 and 3 I'd like to write them as rows at the bottom of the array.  Columns 4 and 5 would move into the original place of columns 2,3 and finally columns 6 and 7 would move as rows underneath columns 4 and 5.  The result would look like this:

```
 [[ 43 153 157 116]
  [108 182  28  67]
  [ 44  81 102  32]
  [143 218 237 194]
  [247  37 100 188]
  [ 39  40  78 165]
  [ 42 244  59 176]
  [236 229 176 237]
  [ 78  77 135 251]
  [143  89 156 206]]
```

I tried to create and new array of zeros with the new shape and add the pieces to the new array but ran into a bunch of error messages for example "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,4) (5,2)" Is there an ideal way of doing this?  Being somewhat new to numpy and array slicing how do I write the contents to the new array in this format.

What is the correct way to even set up this problem?  Do I create an empty array or write a new array and reshape as the rows and columns are manipulated?  I've simplified this example but I actually would like to do this to a greyscale image.

Comment: Read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit the question accodingly.

Comment: When I typed the arrays out in the UI it made them difficult to read and get my point across.  I will try update the question. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than typing all your numbers I'm going to make a (5,8) array like this:

```
In [51]: arr = np.arange(40).reshape(5,8)

In [52]: arr
Out[52]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
       [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]])
```

There are various ways of dividing the array into blocks and then rearranging them.  One straightforward way is to use `np.block` and join 4 two-column blocks.  This may not be the most general, but it's easy to write out:

```
In [53]: np.block([[arr[:,0:2],arr[:,4:6]],[arr[:,2:4],arr[:, 6:8]]])
Out[53]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  5],
       [ 8,  9, 12, 13],
       [16, 17, 20, 21],
       [24, 25, 28, 29],
       [32, 33, 36, 37],
       [ 2,  3,  6,  7],
       [10, 11, 14, 15],
       [18, 19, 22, 23],
       [26, 27, 30, 31],
       [34, 35, 38, 39]])
```

`split` can divide it into those 4 blocks as well:

```
In [54]: alist = np.split(arr, 4, axis=1)

In [55]: alist
Out[55]: 
[array([[ 0,  1],
        [ 8,  9],
        [16, 17],
        [24, 25],
        [32, 33]]),
 array([[ 2,  3],
        [10, 11],
        [18, 19],
        [26, 27],
        [34, 35]]),
 array([[ 4,  5],
        [12, 13],
        [20, 21],
        [28, 29],
        [36, 37]]),
 array([[ 6,  7],
        [14, 15],
        [22, 23],
        [30, 31],
        [38, 39]])]
```

Here's a sequence of reshape and transpose that works:

```
In [64]: arr.reshape(5,2,2,2).transpose(2,0,1,3).reshape(10,4)
Out[64]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  5],
       [ 8,  9, 12, 13],
       [16, 17, 20, 21],
       [24, 25, 28, 29],
       [32, 33, 36, 37],
       [ 2,  3,  6,  7],
       [10, 11, 14, 15],
       [18, 19, 22, 23],
       [26, 27, 30, 31],
       [34, 35, 38, 39]])
```

I arrived at this with some trial and error, aided by previous experience with this kind of regrouping.

Comment: Awesome. This got me started.  Any chance you can explain a bit of the final reshape.transpose.reshape sequence. In the end my example was simplified to get my point across but in reality the array I'm dealing with is a 3024x3024 image and I want to break it into strips of 84 pixels.

Comment: Just look at the results step by step.  First step is to break the array into the smallest blocks that you want to rearrange.  The transpose takes more trial and error.